# I want to crop/cut an image on C#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap

[The image i want to crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yPAL.jpg)
[image cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CsGc.jpg)

I want to crop a image that i have, the size is static and the point is always (0, 0).

I tried somethings I saw in StackOverflow, but they didn't work

```
private void Converter(Image image, int count)
    {
        string name = String.Format("imgTemp\\img{0}.bmp", count);
        Image img = image;
        Bitmap org = new Bitmap(img, 866, 520);
        Bitmap target = org.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, 866, 520), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed); // I convert the image to monochrome and that size
        target.SetResolution(1, 1);
        if (File.Exists(name))
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            File.Delete(name);
            target.Save(name, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            target.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            target.Save(name, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            target.Dispose();
        }
        lbFicheiros.Items.Add(name);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code?

Comment: Please include a small code sample indicating the issue [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Without any code or context, we cannot help you. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) your question to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. You were declaring the org variable with the targeted height/width that is why you could not crop it because it was already that size.

```
private void Converter(Image image, int count)
        {
            string name = String.Format("imgTemp\\img{0}.bmp", count);
            Image img = image;
            Bitmap org = new Bitmap(img); //Changed line
            Bitmap target = org.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, 866, 520), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed); // I convert the image to monochrome and that size
            target.SetResolution(1, 1);
            if (File.Exists(name))
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                File.Delete(name);
                target.Save(name, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                target.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                target.Save(name, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                target.Dispose();
            }
            lbFicheiros.Items.Add(name);
        }
```

Comment: Love you <3 man